# PHP application deployment failed on Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Bitbucket repository that runs a Bitbucket pipeline to deploy the code to GAE. This used to work well until Sept 2018. However, when I tried to trigger the pipeline to deploy some changes to GAE, it fails with

> ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) The current Google Cloud project
>   [MyTestProject] does not contain an App Engine application. Use
>   `gcloud beta app create` to initialize an App Engine application
>   within the project.

I have gone through the Google cloud docs [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/testing-and-deploying-your-app] and it says:

> Before you can deploy your application:
>
> The Owner of the GCP project must enable App Engine.
>
> Ensure that your user account includes the required privileges.

My Bitbucket pipeline account has all the privileges as specified here:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/access-control#primitive_roles

> Note: The App Engine Deployer role alone grants adequate permission to
>   deploy using the Admin API. To use other App Engine tooling, like
>   gcloud commands, you must also have the Storage Admin role and Cloud
>   Build Editor role.

There aren't many helpful docs either that explains why a working deployment pipeline failed.

Here is the bitbucket pipeline yaml.

```
image: myOwnImageOfCentos

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: "Staging deployment"
          deployment: staging
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            # Run composer
            - yum -y update
            - yum install -y unzip git which
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer install
            # Install Google Cloud SDK
            - export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1
            # Google Cloud SDK is pinned for build reliability. Bump if the SDK complains about deprecation.
            - SDK_VERSION=127.0.0
            - SDK_FILENAME=google-cloud-sdk-${SDK_VERSION}-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
            - curl -O -J https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/${SDK_FILENAME}
            - tar -zxvf ${SDK_FILENAME} --directory ${HOME}
            - export PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/google-cloud-sdk/bin
            # Install Google App Engine SDK
            - git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/continuous-deployment-bitbucket.git
            - GAE_PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/google_appengine
            - export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${GAE_PYTHONPATH}
            - python continuous-deployment-bitbucket/scripts/fetch_gae_sdk.py $(dirname "${GAE_PYTHONPATH}")
            # Install app & dev dependencies, test, deploy, test deployment
            - echo ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET} > client-secret.json
            - echo ${APPPARAMETERS_STAGING} > config/parameters.json
            - echo ${APPUSERS_STAGING} > config/users.json
            - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file client-secret.json
            - gcloud app deploy app.yaml --version staging --no-promote --verbosity=warning
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have more than one Project? You cannot delete App Engine, so maybe your App Engine is in a different project.

Comment: Did you already deployed your application on App Engine manually? It may be because App Engine is not initialized for your GCP project.
You may need to open Cloud Shell and use command gcloud app create to initialize App Engine.

Comment: @JohnHanley Yes, I have more than 1 project. What's weird is, the same project worked in September 2018 and I didn't have to run "gcloud beta app create" command. So, I am guessing GAE changed their SDK recently that's breaking the pipeline.

Comment: @GrégoireG. I had deployed my application through Bitbucket pipeline before and it had worked flawlessly. I am not really sure why it's complaining about app engine application not present. Probably, I need to give App Engine Admin role to Bitbucket pipeline user instead of App Engine Deployer role? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/access-control

Comment: It does look like the permissions required for App Engine have changed. If you are using any tooling, then you need App Engine Admin instead of App Engine Deployer.